# Can't get notifications to show up in Android Auto messaging app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-auto

I'm trying to create a messaging app to test Android Auto. However I can't get the notifications to show up on the DHU. I also tested with Facebook Messenger and there it works.

I went pretty much by the development guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/messaging

Just added some hardcoded strings and icons etc. for testing. I have added the required lines to manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
    <service
        android:name=".MessagingService"
        android:exported="true"/>
    ...
</application>
```

This is invoked from a button press:

```
MessagingServiceKt.notify(
    getContext(),
    new YourAppConversation(
        1337,
        "Convo title",
        new ArrayList<YourAppUser>(Arrays.asList(
            new YourAppUser(
                1234,
                "Test1", 
                IconCompat.createWithBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(24,24,Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8))
            ),
            new YourAppUser(
                5345,
                "Test2",
                IconCompat.createWithBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(24,24,Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)),
            )
        ),
        Bitmap.createBitmap(24, 24, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
    )
);
```

Rest of the code looks pretty much the same as in the example, but with hardcoded data for the conversation, user and message objects.

I should be seeing the notification pop up on the DHU unit but it doesn't. I don't get any errors either and all the functions run without fail.

Answer (score 1):

I just got an answer from Google support and it appears you can't get messaging apps to work on Android Auto until your package is published and approved for Android Auto.

So only approved apps installed from the Play Store will work on Android Auto.